# airflow install cannot initdb

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

I'm reinstalling aiflow (after running `pip uninstall apache-airflow`)

Following the airflow's quick start guide I run:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

# install from pypi using pip
pip install apache-airflow

# initialize the database
airflow initdb
```

However I see

> bash: /usr/local/bin/airflow: No such file or directory

How can I initialize the airflow db?

Comment: Did you get any error during installation?

Comment: no i did not...

Comment: Did you install airflow in a virtual environment?

Comment: Try to log out and then log back in. Or even reboot a machine (if you can). If you install in WSL you can just close all terminals open them back.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note for folks who reach here for the same query, wondering why airflow initdb is not working. With future version of airflow you might have to do 
airflow db {init, reset, upgrade}. So for initializing airflow db it will be [**airflow db init**] instead of [**airflow initdb**].

Answer (score 0):

The install worked with `sudo pip install apache-airflow`